# Process Curl Requests with a queue in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP REST server. There is an endpoint where I have a CURL request. This endpoint is the most used endpoint. Process of other code is very fast except for the CURL request. The return value of the curl_exec is not important to me nor the status. So is there a way so that I can put the curl req in aws queue or something so that instead of PHP Server doing the curl, the aws does it later. And in turn the endpoint becomes super fast

Edit

Thing is this can be solved in many ways (example cron, fork, fpsocket etc) but I want the smartest way. One that uses Amazon cloud services like SQS

Comment: Do you mean you want the request done asynchronous to the webbrowser request? Then you have half your answer: Use something containing a list (e.g. a database) and have a cronjob running every X seconds do the task. Your front-end does not have to wait for the AWS request to finish... Otherwise, I don't understand the question and you should elaborate more ;)

Comment: @Raphioly-San I read something about Amazon AWS SQS service. Thing is this can be solved in many ways (example cron, fork, fpsocket etc) but I want the smartest way. One that uses Amazon cloud services.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you in-dept on how to do things the 'AWS' way. I only know how to solve things at a pragmatic level/point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using **Supervisord**(Linux) and **Gearman**. Please check below links for more details

[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)